# Cannot connect to SQL Server on AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect using SQL Studio and although I have followed all the steps in the documentation, I still get error 10060.
I've even made it publicly available to all IPs just to test connection and I still get the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you've opened up the security group, but have you also enabled the "publicly accessible" flag on the RDS instance?

Comment: Yes, see the second screen shot.